# Javascript if else statement execute code based on filters

Tags: javascript

I have the following long if else statement where i check boolean value true then console.log, the problem is the code does not execute when there are two or more values and it stops at the first if statement where it is true and then it skips the rest, How can i make it check if all three filters are true or two filters are true then to execute that block first then go to the next if block , will rewriting it in the order of maximum filter to minimum the only solution ?

```js
var saltyFilter = true
var sourFilter = true
var spicyFilter = true
if (saltyFilter) {
  console.log("salty");
} else if (spicyFilter) {
  console.log("spicy");
} else if (sourFilter) {
  console.log("sour");
} else if (saltyFilter && spicyFilter) {
  console.log("salty & spicy");
} else if (saltyFilter && sourFilter) {
  console.log("salty & sour");
} else if (spicyFilter && sourFilter) {
  console.log("spicy & sour");
} else if (saltyFilter && spicyFilter && sourFilter) {
  console.log("salty, spicy & sour");
} else {
  console.log("unknown flavor");
}
```

in the above the expected result should be as all filters are true

```
"salty, spicy & sour"
```

As a beginner, appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Reverse the order? Check for all three cases first, then the double combinations, then the singles. Or, better, create an array, check each filter only once and push the related string value into the array, then concatenate the array into one string.

Comment: The first condition returns true, that's why the other conditions are not being executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse the order, if saltyFilter is true, then it will always come inside the first code block. Just reverse the order to something like this:

```
if (saltyFilter && spicyFilter && sourFilter) {
  console.log("salty, spicy & sour");
} else if (saltyFilter && sourFilter) {
  console.log("salty & sour");
}  else if (spicyFilter && sourFilter) {
  console.log("spicy & sour");
} else if (saltyFilter && spicyFilter) {
  console.log("salty & spicy");
} else if (saltyFilter) {
  console.log("salty");
} else if (spicyFilter) {
  console.log("spicy");
} else if (sourFilter) {
  console.log("sour");
} else {
  console.log("unknown flavor");
}
```

If you do not understand simple javascript, follow w3Schools, its simple and clear:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could take a function with flas as wanted flavour and return either a joint array or unknown.

```js
function getFlavors(...flags) {
    const flavors = ['salty', 'sour', 'spicy'].filter((_, i) => flags[i]);

    return flavors.length
        ? nice(flavors)
        : 'unknown flavor'
}

function nice([...array]) {
    return array.concat(array.splice(-2, 2).join(' & ')).join(', ');
}

console.log(getFlavors(true, true, true));
console.log(getFlavors(true, false, true));
console.log(getFlavors());
```

Comment: @nina, thank you for this , way advanced for me but thank you for that , really makes me realize how much learning i have to do, i'll break this down to see if i can reuse it :)